# How to install windows 10 using bootcamp?(Hard disk problems)

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

Here's what I did while installing windows 10 using bootcamp.Firstly,i modified the Info.plist file of bootcamp in order to create a live usb(since I have a MBP with an optical drive).It worked.While installing,Windows needed me to have a gpt partition.So,I converted the hybrid MBR/GPT to GPT partition style using the gdisk tool.(before this,I formatted the partition to NTFS format)Again,I booted back to the usb drive and this time,installation started but while finishing up,it gave me an error saying "cannot access boot manager.Installation failed"-(something like that).Any solution?Also,state a way to go back to the original partition style.(In case i decide not to install windows.Also,I am not able to merge the partition since osx is not able to read the partition style).

Comment: What is the year and "screen size" of your Mac? What version of OS X are your running? Does your optical drive work?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have a mid 2010 Mac book Pro(15 inch) running OSx El Capitan(10.11.3).Yes,the optical dive works.

Answer (score 1):

If Apple officially supports Windows 10 on you Mac, then you should follow the instructions given by Apple. See the Apple web site ["Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990) for details.

If apple does not official support your model Mac, you may still be able to install Windows 10. Here are some thoughts.

While editing the `Info.plist` file may allow you to create the USB Windows 10 installer, usually the same computer can not boot the installer from the USB drive. If you can, then your computer is one of the few exceptions.

If you have a working optical drive, then this would make the best choice to install from. I would recommend burning the iso file to a RW DVD. This takes longer to burn, but the DVD is reusable.

When possible, you should use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the "Boot Camp Support Software" to a flash drive. If you can not, then download and use the "Boot Camp Support Software" for Windows 7. The correct version for your Mac can be found at the Apple web site "[Install Windows 7 and earlier on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016)".

If you use an older version of the "Boot Camp Support Software" to install, you made need the set the Compatibility Mode. Right click on `Setup.exe` to set the appropriate mode.

Most likely you will not be able to install using a EFI boot method. Even if you succeed in installing, usually some of the hardware will not function correctly. (For example, sound will not work.)

The best chance at success will be to install using the legacy BIOS boot method. This requires you to partition the installation drive using a hybrid GPT/MBR partition scheme. This usually is accomplished by using the Boot Camp Assistant or using the Disk Utility to format (via Erase) the 4th partition as MS-DOS (FAT). (This is the partition assigned the identifier `disk0s4`.) After booting to the Windows 10 installer, you will need to NTFS format this partition in order to complete the installation of Windows.

If you use the Startup Manager to boot the Windows 10 installer, then you should choose the icon with the label "Windows". This selects the BIOS boot method. The icon labeled "EFI boot" selects a EFI boot method. Again, I recommend you avoid EFI boot method installations. You invoke the Startup Manager by holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key when you turn on or restart your Mac.

Some users have reported problems getting the wireless keyboard to work during the installation process. The Windows installer does offer a "on screen" keyboard which can be temporarily substituted for the physical keyboard. You can pair the wireless keyboard after Windows 10 installs.

It is possible that your computer will boot back to OS X, before the installation of Windows completes. If this happens, then open the "Startup Disk" pane of the "System Preferences" application, select the icon labeled "Windows" and click on the "Restart" button. The installation of Windows will continue.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Using the legacy BIOS boot method,I was able to install windows without any errors.So I suggest others to spend a few bucks on the DVD instead of trying to install using EFI method.